# Can't find out how to compute derivative

Tags: lua, calculus

Yo, guys, I got a question, is there any way to improve this or maybe better way to calculate it? Because the only way to calculate derivative very accurate I can think of is this.. lol, its just logic like d/dx of x^n = nx^(n-1) so I thought of that and tried it out, tho doesnt work with functions like e^x so I need help with make a very accurate derivative calculation

```
function derivative(Function, x)    
    local dxlog = math.log(Function(x), x) 
       
    return dxlog * x^(dxlog - 1)
end 
print(derivative(function(x) return x^3 end, 10))
```

and its so bad it cant even calculate y^x with respect to x..

tried everything I can think of, too dumb to fix this

btw this is the old way I did this:

```
function derivative(Function, x)
    local d = (Function(x + 6.7219579999763e-006) - Function((x - 6.7219579999763e-006))) / 1.3443915999953e-005
    if math.abs(math.round(d) - d) < 4.1212121212e-6 then 
        return math.round(d)
    end
    return d
end
```

Comment: Is the formula available as string (such as `x^3`)?  Or only the function value (such as `function(x) return x^3 end`) is available?

Comment: That's actual problem, if it was available as a string, it would be very easy, but it's not, and I need to do very good approximation

Comment: "very accurate" is not a good description of how accurate you need the result to be, but if you do not have access to the text of the function, you can take the input and output and get the derivative of the point series to get an approximation of the actual derivative, the smaller steps you take for the input value the more accuracy you can squeeze out of this method

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you want to get numerical derivative, not symbolic. Then why not use the most straightforward approach?

```lua
-- lim_{x -> x0} f(x):
local function limit (f, x0, left)
    local x0 = x0 or 0
    local y0 = f (x0)
    if y0 == y0 --[[ not NaN, i.e. 0/0 ]] then
        -- Simplest case: lim_{x -> x0} f(x) = f (x0) (not for derivative, anyway):
        return y0
    end
    local abs = math.abs
    local delta_x = left and -2e-9 or 2e-9
    local y, y1, y2 -- old values of f (x).
    -- Halve delta_x while it is measureable or until f(x) starts to lose accuracy:
    while not y1 or not y2 or abs (delta_x) > 0 and abs (y - y1) < abs (y1 - y2) do
        delta_x = delta_x / 2
        -- Remember changes of y:
        y, y1, y2 = f (x0 + delta_x), y, y1
    end
    return y
end

-- f'(x):
local function derivative (f, left)
    return function (x)
        -- f'(x) = lim_{delta -> 0} (f (x + delta) - f(x)) / delta:
        return limit (function (delta)
            return (f (x + delta) - f (x)) / delta
        end, --[[ delta -> ]] 0, left)
    end
end

-- Example:
local f = function (x)
    return x ^ 3
end

local df = derivative (f)

for _, x in ipairs {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3} do
    print (x, df (x))
end
```

or simplified:

```lua
local delta = 1e-9

local function derivative (f)
    return function (x)
        return (f (x + delta) - f (x)) / delta
    end
end

-- Example:
local f = function (x)
    return x ^ 3
end

local df = derivative (f)

for _, x in ipairs {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3} do
    print (x, df (x))
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I already tried this, just thought maybe there any way to compute numerical derivative different way with most accuracy